# CopyRecordset doesn't paste the results to the excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to paste the results of an SQL Server stored procedure to worksheet called *Testing*, but it doesn't copy the results of a stored procedure. The stored procedure should pick up the date from a worksheet called *Rater* and execute the SP based on the date and then copy the result table to a worksheet called *Testing*.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```vb
Sub NewCADRate()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim iCols As Integer

    'Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rater")

    'Opens the Results tab
    With Sheets("Testing")
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        Range("A1").Select
    End With
    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("Rater").Activate
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Data Source=10.50.32.92; Initial Catalog = Property; Trusted_connection=Yes; Provider=SQLOLEDB;"

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    cmd.CommandText = "Global_CurrencyConverter"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PED", adDate, adParamInput, 50, Range("Effectivedate").Value)       
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Execute      

    'Open Recordset'        
    Set rst.Source = cmd
    rst.Open
    For iCols = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Testing").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rst.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    'Copy Data to Excel'       
    Worksheets("Testing").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Worksheets("Testing").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    If rst.EOF Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have an `On Error Resume Next` statement in the middle of your code. What happens when you remove it? Also, you should use `Range("Effectivedate").Value2` to avoid issues with implicit type conversion.

Comment: Also `Dim ... As New ADODB.Connection` is a very bad idea IMO. `Dim ... As New {Anything}` is a bad idea, period. But yeah, you're not getting results because you're ignoring a runtime error, obviously.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Although the way Emily wrote the code with the `Dim` inline and immediately using the variable on the next line is the best possible way to avoid the issues of a non-instantiated object floating around.

Comment: @robinCTS auto-instantiated locals **cannot be destroyed**. Single best way to keep a live object reference floating around. Go ahead, set it to `Nothing` all you want - VBA will recreate it as soon as you check if it's *nothing*. Auto-instantiated variables are a trap.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I wasn't saying it wasn't a turd. I was simply pointing out that it was the most polished you could get it ;)

Comment: @robinCTS meh.. IMO the single best way to ensure proper cleanup and initialization is to use `With New ADODB.Connection`. No local variable, object is out of scope at `End With`. Only problem with that, is passing the object to a `Command`. Still, `With New` is underused and underrated.

Comment: I completely agree with declaring variables as close as possible to their usage though. *Consistently*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I use it all the time. Not so much with ADODB  but with regexes and anything else I can get away with